# Get data to Angular App from Oauth popup

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, oauth

I'm trying to get json data back from an oauth popup to my angular app. I've created an interval to check for data in the popup. The data gets returned to the popup as json, but I can't get it back to the main app.

When I try this method, I get a error:

> DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:9000" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

My code for this is:

```
this.socialLogin = function(provider) {
  $window.$scope = $rootScope;

   var url = urlBase + '/' + provider,
     width = 1000,
     height = 650,
     top = (window.outerHeight - height) / 2,
     left = (window.outerWidth - width) / 2,
     interval = 1000;

  var options = 'width=' + width + ',height=' + height + ',scrollbars=0,top=' + top + ',left=' + left;

  var socialPopup = $window.open(url, 'Social Login', options);

  // create an ever increasing interval to check a certain global value getting assigned in the popup
  var i = $interval(function(){
    interval += 500;
    try {
      // value is the user_id returned
      if (socialPopup.value){
        $interval.cancel(i);
        socialPopup.close();
      }
    } catch(e){
      console.error(e);
    }
  }, interval);
```

};